# Backup Database command in T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

```
set @TSQL=      'BACKUP DATABASE ['+@DBName +'] TO  DISK = N'''+@FilePath+'\'+@DBName+'_backup_'+@Date+'.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'''+@FilePath+'\'+@DBName+'_backup_'+@Date+''', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10'
```

I have the above T SQL statement to backup my database. On running the same statement twice, the previous backup set is overwritten and the size of the backup is increased. I am confused between the interaction of NOINIT and SKIP in the above statement.

According to MSDN:

NOINIT: Controls whether the backup operation appends to or overwrites the existing backup sets on the backup media. The default is to append to the most recent backup set on the media.

However i have noticed my backup size is increasing exponentially on taking backup of the same database a second time.

Can anyone explain how this command will function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a .bak file you can have more than one backup, so basically what you set when specifying INIT/NOINIT is to overwrite the full .bak file (which is a backup set not a single backup) or just put your backup inside it with the previous backups.
Try to restore the backup and you'll see that you can choose a specific backup from your backup set.

SKIP checks the expiration date of the backup before overwriting it, in case you choose to do it instead of appending the backups after each other into the .bak file.

More details here (I guess you already visited it, but just in case): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186865(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Can you please specify your main requirement, so I may help

Comment: @MSANZ   Thank you for your quick reply, Im using this statement to take backup of my database everyday at 12 AM, If i have understood your statement correctly, if i take the backup each day twice, the old backup as well as the new backup both will exist in the .bak file (ie , the backup set) I have written the script to run only once a day, but i am just curious to what will happen if its running twice. (the names of the backup the next day will be different since the date is different).

Comment: Your guesses are right. Take into account that INIT/NOINIT will append/overwrite your backup set, which is specified in the `NAME` argument. In this case the name of your .bak file is determined by the date, so unless you perform the backups more than once per day you'll always have 1 backup -> 1 file.